# Error executing SQL commands to update table

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee

Hi every One I am trying to add column in Mysql.

My Sql Query is Given Below

```
CREATE TABLE  `mtrans`.`order` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_date` date NOT NULL,
  `order_by` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

But when i add one more column it will give some error like that.

My error log is given below

```
Error executing SQL commands to update table.
        MySQL Error Nr. 1064
        You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AFTER `amount`' at line 1
```

Comment: please update the query that you've executed

Comment: What is the actual SQL you are trying to execute?

Comment: post your tables sql script and query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [alter table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) in mysql.

I'm assuming you've already created `order table` successfully.

Simple alter table to add column in existing table.

```
ALTER TABLE order ADD order_no VARCHAR(10);
```

query to add column after a existing column.

```
ALTER TABLE order ADD order_no VARCHAR(10) AFTER [Order];
```